Почему метод Canvas.delete() не полностью удаляет id элементов(rectangle, oval, text)?
Всем доброго времени суток, я новичок в tkinter, python. Прошу совета как побороть такую проблему. Для этого я написал 2 маленькие программы, демонстрирующие мое непонимание.
Суть проблемы: На Canvas есть множество разных элементов(фигуры, текст), все они имеют свой id(id_rect = canvas.create_rect(...) или id_text = canvas.create_text(...) по сути это порядок их отрисовки).Далее я хочу чтобы Canvas очищался по нажатию на кнопку(то есть чтобы я потом нарисовал новые элементы). Но после использования метода canvas.delete() и рисования новых элементов на Canvas, tkinter присваивает элементам последующие номера, то есть не с нового круга.
В дальнейшем я хочу без проблем пользоваться методом canvas.find_withtag('rect'), который возвращать будет некорректный список id элементов имеющий тег 'rect'
Например: было 10 треугольников(их id =(1...11)), я очистил canvas, нарисовал еще 10 треугольников (их id должны быть тоже (1...11), но их id = (11...21))
Вот простая программа которая это демонстрирует:
  import tkinter as tk
  import random
  class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
      super().__init__(master)
      self.master = master
      self.pack()
      self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400)
      self.canvas.pack()
      self.create_widgets()
      def create_widgets(self):
      self.draw_button = tk.Button(self, text="Draw", command=self.draw_triangle(10))
      self.draw_button.pack()
      self.clear_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.clear_canvas)
      self.clear_button.pack()

    def draw_triangle(self,num_triangles):
      for _ in range(num_triangles):
        x1 = random.randint(0, 400)
        y1 = random.randint(0, 400)
        x2 = random.randint(0, 400)
        y2 = random.randint(0, 400)
        x3 = random.randint(0, 400)
        y3 = random.randint(0, 400)
        self.canvas.create_polygon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, tags="rect", 
                                 fill=random.choice(["red", "green", "blue"]))
        self.canvas.update()
      self.canvas.tag_bind("rect", "<Enter>", self.get_id)

    def get_id(self, event):
      id = self.canvas.find_withtag("current")
      print("ID:", id[0])

    def clear_canvas(self):
      self.canvas.delete("all")
      self.canvas.update()
  root = tk.Tk()
  app = Application(master=root)
  app.mainloop()

Зато работает как надо, если метод canvas.delete() заменить на canvas.destroy(), но при таком подходе нужно каждый раз пересоздавать canvas, чего хотелось бы избежать.
Вот переписанная выше программа с методом canvas.destroy()
import tkinter as tk
import random
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        # self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400)
        # self.canvas.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400)
        # self.canvas.pack()
        # self.draw_triangle(10)
        self.draw_button = tk.Button(self, text="Draw", command=lambda: self.draw_triangle(10))
        self.draw_button.pack()
        self.clear_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.clear_canvas)
        self.clear_button.pack()

    def draw_triangle(self,num_triangles):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()
        for _ in range(num_triangles):
            x1 = random.randint(0, 400)
            y1 = random.randint(0, 400)
            x2 = random.randint(0, 400)
            y2 = random.randint(0, 400)
            x3 = random.randint(0, 400)
            y3 = random.randint(0, 400)
            self.canvas.create_polygon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, tags="rect", fill=random.choice(["red", "green", "blue"]))
            self.canvas.update()
        self.canvas.tag_bind("rect", "<Enter>", self.get_id)

    def get_id(self, event):
        id = self.canvas.find_withtag("current")
        print("ID:", id[0])

    def clear_canvas(self):
        # self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.canvas.update()
        self.canvas.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()

Помогите разобраться, спасибо!

Ну это логично для фреймворка - просто инкрементировать счётчик, а не искать каждый раз, какие id свободны, а какие нет. Держите свой словарь перенумерации, если хотите другую нумерацию сделать. Эти то id для внутреннего употребления, пользователь вообще не должен их видеть, по идее.

Почему эти id для внутреннего пользования, если метод canvas.find_withtag(“recr”) как раз и возвращает массив id (который генерируется Tkinter-ом) всех элементов имеющих этот тэг. Получается это единственный способ однозначно идентифицировать конкретную фигуру

Ну и? Зачем вам именно чтобы с 1 нумерация id их была? id у вас есть, количество их тоже есть.

Проблема в том что по данному идентификатору я в дальнейшем обращаюсь к конкретной фигуре и меняю ее параметры, если эти идентификаторы после delete() не обнуляются то мне кажется это как то странным решением

А при создании фигур вы не можете сразу получать их ID? Или получить сразу все ID фигур с таким тагом? Не вижу больших проблем. Вы то знаете, когда вы их удаляете и создаёте заново, в этот момент и нужно получить новые ID.
